# How to highlight and underline grammar mistakes in Listview Builder using Flutter in chatbot?

Tags: flutter, artificial-intelligence, flutter-dependencies, openai-api

I want to create a chatbot in Flutter in which I can type English Sentences and check them to highlight and underline grammar mistakes.

What I want is that the user input should be checked using openAI and any mistakes in the user input should be underlined in Flutter UI.

I want to make the same as the below image.

[image]